# Как временно выключить внешний ключ в db2?

Tags: sql, linux, база-данных, db2, constraints

Нужно на время выключить, затем включить внешние ключи в таблицах. 
Пытался как [здесь](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ru/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0020167.html)(внизу страницы). Получилось:

```
alter table client foreign key(address_id) not enforced
```

Результат выполнения:

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
>   valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
>   SQL0104N  An unexpected token "not" was found following "eign 
>   key(address_id)".  Expected tokens may include:  "".
>   SQLSTATE=42601

Пробовал разный синтаксис.

Answer (score 0):

Если оставить в стороне диалект DB2, то внешний ключ нельзя отключить.
Его можно удалить, а потом воссоздать.

```
Alter table ... drop constraint ...
Alter table ... add constraint ...
```